# SMTP response for unspecified system error

Tags: smtp

What SMTP response code and message should be used for an unspecified system error in processing the request?

[RFC 5321 §4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.2) states:

> An SMTP server SHOULD send only the reply codes listed in this
> document. An SMTP server SHOULD use the text shown in the examples
> whenever appropriate.

What should an SMTP server implementation do for an error that does not fit any of the listed codes and descriptions?

The HTTP specification has a response code `500` for a non-specific “Internal Server Error”. What is the appropriate SMTP equivalent that stays within the bounds of the above “SHOULD” admonitions?

Comment: 451 looks generic enough. I don't think any 5xx is an appropriate way for the server to say "I have no idea what's wrong" - if it doesn't know what's wrong, it doesn't know that a retry later won't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

The more correct return code for generic errors seems **451**

From the RFC:

> 451  Requested action aborted: error in processing

If you, for some reasons, feel that 451 is not adequate, you can use 430 or 440:

> 4yz  Transient Negative Completion reply
>
> x3z  Unspecified.
>
> x4z  Unspecified.

Comment: The problem with this is that the client will probably retry in a few hours, and carry on retrying. `554 Transaction has failed` seems like a better bet to me, while you find and fix the problem.